# Set some InfoPath 2007 form column to be edit-able in SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, forms-services, forms-library

How do we set some column to be editable and some not editable for InfoPath 2007 form column in SharePoint Designer 2007?

Details:
Suppose there is a InfoPath 2007 Form library that contain 3 fields (which 2 fields - "ID" and "Status" are promoted from InfoPath 2007 and 1 field - "Quantity" are text field) and all fields are needed to be display in the custom aspx file (after dragging the Data Source library into the aspx file). what configuration are needed to be set in order to allow 'Status' and 'Quantity' to be edit-able while 'ID' not editable?

Comment: Are you connecting to a previously created list where these fields are or a manually created data source where you intend to have these fields populated by a formula or something?

Comment: @Lori, actually this is a data source tool in SharePoint designer 2007 pointing to a created sharepoint 2007 form library. The fields are instant populated with the data inside the SharePoint 2007 form library into the data source. The data source tool basically just need to display those data.